# What level is a spell if you cast it without expending a spell slot?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-slots

There are ways to cast spells without expending a spell slot such as:

**Master Transmuter** (PHB 119):

> ***Restore Life.*** You cast the *raise dead* spell on a creature you touch
>   with the transmuter’s stone, without expending a spell slot or needing
>   to have the spell in your spellbook.

**Armor of Shadows** (PHB 110):

> You can cast *mage armor* on yourself at will, without expending a spell slot or material components.

**Whispers of the Grave** (PHB 111):

> You can cast *speak with dead* at will, without expending a spell
>   slot.

See also: **Channel Divinity: Read Thoughts** (PHB 59-60), **Mystic Arcanum** (PHB 108), **Beast Speech** (PHB 110), **Chains of Carceri** (PHB 110), **Eldritch Sight** (PHB 110), **Fiendish Vigor** (PHB 111), **Mask of Many Faces** (PHB 111), **Master of Myriad Forms** (PHB 111), **Misty Visions** (PHB 111), **Otherwordly Leap** (PHB 111), **Signature Spells** (PHB 115), **Spell Mastery** (PHB 115), **Shapechanger** (PHB 119), **Boon of Spell Mastery** (DMG 232) and **Boon of Spell Recall** (DMG 232).

What level are these spells if you cast them without expending a spell slot?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The Sage Advice Compendium goes into detail about what happens when you cast a spell without expending a spell slot:

A spell is cast at its lowest possible level, which is the level that appears near the top of its description. Unless you have a special ability that says otherwise or the origin of what allows you to cast a spell without expending a spell slot also allows you specifically to expend a higher-level spell
slot when you cast it; and that the only way to increase the level of a spell is to expend a higher-level spell slot when you cast it.

[Sage Advice Compendium version 2.3, page 13](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=13):

> **What level is a spell if you cast it without a spell slot?**
>
> Such a spell is cast at its lowest possible level, which is the level
>   that appears near the top of its description. Unless you have a
>   special ability that says otherwise, the only way to increase the
>   level of a spell is to expend a higher-level spell slot when you cast
>   it. (p 13)

If you have the option to cast a spell at a higher level you have to regard the rules for **Casting A Spell at a Higher Level** (PHB 201):

> When a spellcaster casts a spell using a slot that is of a higher level than the spell, the spell assumes the higher level for that casting.

These origins (in the PHB) of what allows you to cast a spell without expending a spell slot also allows you specifically to expend a higher-level spell slot when you cast it:

**Spell Mastery** (PHB 115):

> If you want to cast either spell at a higher level, you must expend a
>   spell slot as normal.

**Signature Spells** (PHB 115):

> If you want to cast either spell at a higher level, you must expend a
>   spell slot as normal.

An example of special abilities that say otherwise is:

**Infernal Legacy** (PHB 43):

> Once you reach 3rd level, you can cast the *hellish rebuke* spell once per day
>   as a 2nd-level spell.

That allows you to cast the first-level spell *[Hellish Rebuke](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hellish-rebuke)* as a second level spell; that is at a higher level than normal, but only at that level.

The wording in the Sage Advice Compendium follows the already in the DMG established wording of:

**Boon of Spell Mastery** (DMG 232)

> Choose one 1st-level sorcerer, warlock, or wizard spell that you can
>   cast. You can now cast that spell at its lowest level without
>   expending a spell slot.