# Does Psionic Sorcery value spell levels differently than Flexible Casting?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, spellcasting, sorcerer, spell-slots

In attempting to answer [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/180065/48793) I ran into a different question about how the Abberant Mind Sorcerer's Psionic Sorcery works.

Psionic Sorcery states:

> When you cast any spell of 1st level or higher from your Psionic Spells feature, you can cast it by expending a spell slot as normal **or by spending a number of sorcery points equal to the spell’s level**.

Normally, a sorcerer must spend increasingly large quantities of sorcery points to make spell slots as indicated on the [table under Font of Magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#FontofMagic-371) and can create spell slots no higher than level 5.

However, Psionic Sorcery is worded as "a number of points equal to the spell's level." This would seem to suggest that the conversion rate is always 1:1. That is, to cast a level 5 spell, an Abberant Mind Sorcerer would only need to expend 5 sorcery points, not 7.

Further, the Psionic Sorcery seems to allow *any* level spell to be cast in this way. The ability does not seem to be limited to a maximum of level 5 spell slots since it isn't explicitly predicated on the table from Flexible Casting.

Is that correct?

Comment: @Thom, I changed the title a little bit to hopefully clarify what I'm asking. I had understood Psionic Sorcery to add the ability to cast without VS or potentially M components and without needing to expend a bonus action to convert but I realized that it also seems to use a completely different system to value a spell's level than flexible casting, which seemed odd and to me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Yes. Here is a table.

| Spell level | Flexible Casting SP | Psionic Sorcery SP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 5 | 3 |
| 4 | 6 | 4 |
| 5 | 7 | 5 |
| 6 | NA | 6 |
| 7 | NA | 7 |
| 8 | NA | 8 |
| 9 | NA | 9 |

The second column is taken directly from the Font of Magic feature, and the third column is a direct application of the Psionic Sorcery feature which says:

> by spending a number of sorcery points equal to the spell’s level.

These columns are clearly different, which makes sense, these are different features. It would be silly to give a sorcerer subclass a feature that replicates a class feature they already have.

Note, it may be unclear if you can upcast spells using Psionic Sorcery. This question has conflicting answers: [Can Aberrant Mind Sorcerers upcast Psionic Spells using Sorcery points?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/180065/can-aberrant-mind-sorcerers-upcast-psionic-spells-using-sorcery-points). You mileage may vary for levels 6-9 on this table, depending on how you interpret Psionic Sorcery.

#### Psionic Sorcery *only* lets you cast spells learned through the 1st level Psionic Spells feature.

Psionic Sorcery says:

> When you cast any spell of 1st level or higher *from your Psionic Spells feature*...

Psionic Spells says:

> You learn additional spells when you reach certain levels in this class, as shown on the Psionic Spells table.

Only spells from this table can be cast with SP through the Psionic Sorcery feature.

Comment: Ah. That last part about it being limited to the spells on the Psionic Spells is what I was failing to grasp. Thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: It may be worth noting that, although the Psionic Sorcery feature doesn't limit itself to 5th level spells, the Psionic Spells feature does. Psionic Sorcery also doesn't seem to allow for upcasting, so I don't think there's actually a way to use the 6-9th level options.

Comment: @KamilDrakari See my answer here:[Can Aberrant Mind Sorcerers upcast Psionic Spells using Sorcery points?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/180068) I argue that you can upcast with psionic sorcery.

Comment: Minor correction: psionic spells aren't limited to the ones in the table. The feature has a spell replacement mechanism allowing you to swap in a divination or enchantment spell from the wizard, sorcerer or warlock list. You could then cast these spells with sorcery points as psionic spells.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes, your interpretation seems to be correct

The two effects that you list - Flexible Casting and Psionic Sorcery - are just that: two different effects. You can use either-or-both, at your discretion. This is just one of the benefits to choosing the Abberant Mind Sorcerer over others.

It could also potentially be useful having access to both features - depending on what the answer to the other question is. If in fact you cannot upcast using Psionic Sorcery, it may be worth it to you to spend extra sorcery points to get the higher-level spell slot in order to upcast (Again, this is all depending on what the answer to the linked question turns out to be).